# How to set the region of variable in the ParametricPlot?

Tags: parametric-functions

I would like to make a 3D ParametricPlot with a certain region.

The parametric equations is $X(p_1,p_2)$, $Y(p_1,p_2)$ and $T(p_1,p_2)$. I want a 3D plot with $T(X,Y)$, I do the following,

```
ParametricPLot3D[{X,Y,T},{p1,a,b},{p2,c,d}].
```

Here the variables $p_1$ and $p_2$ should fall into a specified range $0<p1^2+p2^2<5$. Therefore, I use `RegionFunction`

```
ParametricPLot3D[{X,Y,T},{p1,a,b},{p2,c,d},
  RegionFunction -> Function[{u, v, w}, 0<u^2+v^2<5]
]
```

. The problem is the `u` and `v` in the `RegionFunction` are corresponding to $X$ and $Y$ not $p_1$ and $p_2$. If I want to set the region for variables $p_1$ and $p_2$ for the `ParametricPlot`, what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) for `RegionFunction` explains that for `ParametricPlot3D` the arguments to the function are `Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, ...]`. Changing to that function signature should work.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply.

Do you mean that if I set the Function[{x,y,z,u,v}, 0<x^2+y^2<5]....is x and y here are corresponding to variable p1 and p2 not for parametric function X and Y?

Comment: `u` and `v` are corresponding to your `p1` and `p2`. `x`, `y` and `z` are corresponding to your `X`, `Y` and `T`. So you could also just write `Function[{x, y, t, p1, p2}, 0<p1^2+p2^2<5]` to correspond to your variable naming. Mathematiac doesn't really care about the naming of the function parameters.

Comment: Do you mean that the name is not important what make sense is the sequence? 
Function[{A,B,C,D,E}]......

A,B,C are the corresponding parametric functions in the ParametricPlot (ParametricPlot[{X,Y,T},{p1,a,b},{p2,a,b}])..
A for X, B for Y, C for T, the remain two D and E are corresponding to the variables D for p1 and E for p2. Is that so?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can also see this when using the alternative `Slot[]` notation for functions. In your case we could for example write: `(0 < #4^2 + #5^2 < 5 &)` where `#4` and `#5` are the fourth and fifth function arguments and `&` denotes the end of the anonymous function.

Comment: Your comments are really helpful for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome!